# How to insert public key and hash signature generated in smart card in a CSR with openssl API's

Tags: csr

1)I am generating a Key file and a CSR with the help of openssl commands. 
When displaying the CSR information with command “ openssl req -in test_csr.pem -noout –text” I get the following printings:

```
Certificate Request:
Data:
    Version: 0 (0x0)
    Subject: C=GB, O=Test
    Subject Public Key Info:
        Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
        RSA Public Key: (2048 bit)
            Modulus (2048 bit):
                00:a6:af:51:e9:23:65:50:27:14:83:f5:c8:11:10:
                b1:03:0b:c7:0d:2d:ae:09:81:d9:f8:31:ad:8e:d7:
                8e:65:a8:e0:d4:b4:7e:f9:3e:99:fa:b0:43:5d:e0:
                41:7a:ee:9f:90:3d:05:c0:6f:80:bb:bb:9e:dd:64:
                1e:15:89:0c:bc:e6:3d:76:4e:d0:ef:5c:e4:de:34:
                00:d0:ac:5c:e4:f8:73:b7:22:12:81:30:28:85:cd:
                5a:bb:d6:28:c3:dc:01:67:f5:56:3a:3f:01:f3:d7:
                8f:d9:19:67:90:1e:23:24:b0:58:e9:80:44:c9:36:
                ae:2b:c3:81:a3:ce:de:af:8b:32:33:7d:f7:81:d7:
                80:b8:d2:97:ce:8b:f3:21:2b:e8:e2:96:d0:b1:3f:
                cc:dc:18:18:c1:e7:99:81:2a:e9:45:20:b7:80:39:
                b3:5d:b3:ab:61:6a:61:f3:e1:7c:32:b7:a8:29:1a:
                b2:e1:02:81:42:1f:b4:c3:7f:bf:21:f6:2d:4f:ec:
                19:d4:3a:d4:bf:90:8a:3b:f0:24:cf:83:1b:21:ab:
                b2:cb:15:38:f2:ac:1d:80:ba:33:2b:c8:f4:8d:52:
                90:7a:25:2b:e5:08:68:a2:f2:84:61:2f:24:48:a9:
                25:97:85:28:64:52:f9:15:91:eb:36:c6:d9:98:08:
                09:d3
            Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
    Attributes:
        a0:00
```

Now when I edit the key file in DER format with an Hex editor, I get the following data

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

I observe that in addition to the Key (from byte 33) as is it displayed in the previous step, there is extra data before the key (32 first bytes) and after the key (5 last bytes).
Does somebody know where the extra information comes from and how to decrypt it?

2)I have to test a configuration where the pair of the Keys (private and public) and the hash signature are generated in a smart card with the help of vendor API’s.  With a first API I get the Public Key and Length from the smart card. With a second API I a get the hash signature data and length.
I guess that the Public key can be inserted in the CSR with openssl X509_REQ_set_pubkey API (is it correct?).
The question is: Is there an existing openssl API I can use to insert the hash signature in the CSR (something like X509_REQ_sign but without hashing and signature process that has already been done by the smart card).
Thanks.
P.L.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First 256 bytes should be structure describing certificates owner (Subject, algorithm, etc).
Last 5 bytes is the RSA public exponent - 65537 in ASN.1 encoding.
To get more information use ASN.1 decoder (or openssl asn1parse command).

Unfortunately I don't know about such function on OpenSSL and don't have time to dig into their sources, but at least it is possible to form CSR ASN.1 structure manually, that's not that hard.

Comment: Can you recommend a good reference where CSR ASN.1 structure is clearly explained (before digging into the code)?

Comment: It's PKCS#10/RFC 2986. Also you'll need to read some text about DER (it is also simple - tag + length + data).